# FTP para FTP IIS server

Tags: iis, ftp

Bons dias,

Estou a utilizar o ftp do Ubuntu para transferir um ficheiro para IIS ftp server. Neste servidor de ftp os nomes de utilizador aceitam o seguinte formato:

```
username|usernameB
```

devido ao isolamento de utlizadores.

O seguinte comando nao funciona devido ao pipe - |.

```
ftp username|usernameB@host
```

tentei fazer escape do nome de várias formas, por exemplo:

```
ftp username%7CusernameB@host
```

no modo interactivo consigo aceder colocando o host primeiro e depois o utilizador e palavra-passe.

Alguma sugestao? Ou aplicativo que possa instalar em ubuntu que permita relaizar isto na linha de comando?

agradecido

Answer (score 1):

Consegui aceder, desligando o modo interactivo e 'escaping' o caracter pipe ('|') - utilizado pelo servidor de ftp do IIS para utilizador em modo de isolamento. Resposta baseada em 'thread' de LinuxQuestions.org:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=a.b.c
USER=jenkins.a.b.c\|jenkins
PASS=xxxxxxxxx

# -i turns off interactive mode

ftp -inv $HOST << EOF

user $USER $PASS

.
.
.
ftp operations (ex. cd /folder/folder)
.
.
.

bye
EOF
```